# Flickering text on css transform scale

Tags: css, text, scale, css-transforms, flicker

people. I`m new to this,  and I have an issue with some text flickering when I try to scale the div up. Can, please, somebody look at my case at help me with a solution to this? Thanks in advance! The pen is this https://codepen.io/alinfarcas/pen/eYXqwLM

The best solution that I came up with was

```
&__parc {
    box-shadow: 0 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    border-radius: 10px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    will-change: transform;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;

    &:hover {
      transform: scale(1.04);
      box-shadow: 0 24px 48px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    }
  }
```

But, in this case, even if the text is not flickering anymore, it becames blurry when I hover, and remains blurry even after the hover stops. Can u help me? Thank you!

Comment: Which browser are you using? Your Codepen seems to work fine on my browser (Safari on Mac).

Comment: I`m using Chrome on Windows 10, but the issue is present also in Firefox and Edge, because I checked.

Comment: scaling text on a non 4k/retina display will cause artefacts. text rendering is a super complicated issue and the glyphs are usually optimized for the particular font-size. if you just transform-scale ist, you get a lot of aliasing etc.

Comment: I see... :) There must be a way...

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had this issue many times here’s what I use

-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale

Comment: I tried with your fix, but it is still not working. I tried all the combinations between what I had and what you gave me. :( Thanks anyway, for the answer!